# How to store enum in SQLite database

Tags: c++, sql, qt, sqlite, enums

I'm trying to store enum in SQLite database using QSql.
I have following class:

**partydao.h:**

```
class PartyDao : public QObject
{
public:
  enum partyType { typeCompany, typePerson };

private:

  Q_OBJECT
  Q_ENUMS(partyType)
  Q_PROPERTY(partyType type READ type WRITE set_type)

  // other declarations
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(PartyDao::partyType)
```

**partydao.cpp:**

```
#include "partydao.h"

static int id = qRegisterMetaType<PartyDao::partyType>("partyType");
```

I do insert like this:

```
PartyDao p;
p.setProperty("type", QVariant::fromValue(PartyDao::typePerson));

QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("INSERT INTO party (type) values (:type)");
qDebug() << p.property("type").isNull();
query.bindValue(":type", p.property("type"));
query.exec();
```

Although qDebug() prints "false" (i.e. property is **not** null), null value is stored in db.

I've tried with column of type TEXT and INTEGER with no success.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I've just checked and QVariant holding my enum claims it can't be converted to QString or int (`canConvert<int>()` and `canConvert<QString>()` return false). Is there a way to add this conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find any way to use auto conversion of QVariants of user type. Therefore I've created singleton storing rules for conversion.

```
struct DbConverter
{
  virtual ~DbConverter() {}

  virtual QVariant toDbValue(const QVariant &value) = 0;
  virtual QVariant fromDbValue(const QVariant &value) = 0;
};


class DbConversion
{
public:
  static QVariant toDbValue(const QVariant &value)
  {
    return instance()->m_converters.contains(value.userType()) ?
            instance()->m_converters[value.userType()]->toDbValue(value) :
            value;
  }

  static QVariant fromDbValue(int type, const QVariant &value)
  {
    return instance()->m_converters.contains(type) ?
            instance()->m_converters[type]->fromDbValue(value):
            value;
  }

  static int setConverter(int typeId, DbConverter *converter)
  {
    instance()->m_converters[typeId] = converter;
    return typeId;
  }

private:
  static DbConversion *instance()
  {
    static DbConversion *inst = new DbConversion;
    return inst;
  }

  QHash<int, DbConverter*> m_converters;
};
```

I register my custom types using value returned from `qRegisterMetaType()` and perform conversions on each app<->db transfer.

Please let me know if you find any more elegant solution and I'll be happy to accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign initial value to the first element in your enum, and the compiler will auto-increment any further definitions, then save this value to your database? You may have to cast it back and forth between an int, but qvariant should take care of that for you.

ie

```
enum partyType { typeCompany=1, typePerson };
```

Comment: If the first enumerator has no initial value it is by default assigned with 0.